# Unable to call back the name of the method I am while in it

Tags: java, methods, callback, restart

I am making simple calculator program that initially and simply asks for a number in regards to addition, subtraction and division. 
If they enter a number that is not 1,2 or 3 I want to create an IOException and then recall the method to allow the user to be asked the same question again.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any help appreciated. Thank you.
((Assume that scanner and all other functions are working))

`public static void mathsChoice() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("'1' for Addition, '2' for Subtraction, '3' for Division");
        int resChoice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (resChoice == 1){
            additionMethod();
        }else if (resChoice == 2){
            subtractionMethod();
        }   else if (resChoice == 3){
            divisionMethod();
        }else {
              throw new IOException("Not valid, try again.");
              mathsChoice();
            }
        }`

The "mathsChoice();" within the else clause is causing the error: 
"Unreachable code"

```
mathsChoice();
```

Comment: *Maybe I'm missing something obvious.* Maybe not obvious, but very basic. What do you think throwing an exception does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that `mathsChoice()` has no chance of execution ever. As in that particular block you are always throwing an exception which will terminate the program execution and the program will never reach this line `mathsChoice()`

You should put the `mathsChoice()` call after the else block is closed.

```
public static void mathsChoice() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("'1' for Addition, '2' for Subtraction, '3' for Division");
        int resChoice = scanner.nextInt();
        if (resChoice == 1){
            additionMethod();
        }else if (resChoice == 2){
            subtractionMethod();
        }   else if (resChoice == 3){
            divisionMethod();
        }else {
              throw new IOException("Not valid, try again.");
        }
     mathsChoice();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you throw the `IOException` the method exits, and the `mathsChoice();` line is never reached.

You may want to change it to a simple print out instead of an exception. `System.out.println("Not valid, try again.");`